# Quantity is less than 6 automatically out of stock selected in the admin grid

Tags: magento2

For the particular attribute type If the Quantity is less than 6 then automatically Stock avaliablity from stock to Out of Stock

Comment: Prepare a cron and if quantity less than 6 for products, than use code in cron.

Comment: we have to run the cron daily

Comment: It's upto you, at 6 hours or 12 hours. 
https://crontab.guru/#*_*_*_*